# Does changing or removing file extension trick antivirus software?

Tags: windows, virus, anti-virus, file-extension

I have little experience of antivirus software. I wish someone help me with common antivirus behaviors.

For example, I have an EXE or PDF file containing virus.

Does removing the `.exe`/`.pdf` or changing the file extension to `txt` prevent antivirus software from detecting the virus?

Or it varies from case to case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the antivirus software and the configuration you have selected.  Setting it to scan every file should result in the virus being found - assuming it is known.  However, some settings like "quick scan" or changing the file extension might result in the file being skipped.

On access scanning is a much better than a scheduled scan.  On access scanning will look at every file as it is being accessed, which is much better than the tradition scan.  However, on access scanning can fail to detect files as well if not properly configured.

Answer (score 1):

In short no. An extension tells the OS how to interact with the file. The file itself contains information that would identify what it is. That is what most antivirus looks for. Changing the extension will not obfuscate its identity